# Magento Custom Product Price change base on product

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

I want to change custom products prices I want to add price of each product in to cart, here I have attached screen shot[image]

Here I have add add price of 8.29 for Qty 2 and 23.85 for Qty 6 I want to use this price in cart.

Existing feature is working like

if I add any amount in option 2: like I have add amount 4.19

and our original price amount is 4.19

then it will show 4.19 + 4.19 = 8.28

I don't want to use this calculation, I want to use my product price in to cart.

Is this possible? If yes then How?